# Was bedeutet das Liedtitel »Wüde Weiber« von Sumawind?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialect

Was bedeutet der Liedtitel ***Wüde Weiber*** von *Sumawind?* Ich weiß, dass *Weiber* auf Englisch *women* bedeutet, aber ich kann keine Übersetzung von *wüde* finden, die für mich Sinn macht.

Hier ist ein Link: https://youtu.be/qCS5A3MLswA.

Ich verstehe nur ein bisschen von dem Songtext.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sumawind ist eine Dialektband aus Wien, sie singen im Wiener Dialekt. Der Wiener Dialekt gehört wie fast alle in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte zu den bairischen Dialekten. (Die einzige Ausnahme sind die alemannischen Dialekte in Vorarlberg, ganz im Westen Österreichs.) Wenn man es genauer klassifizieren will, gehören die Wiener Dialekte zu den donaubairischen Dialekten.

In Wien werden mehrere verschiedene Dialekte gesprochen, die einander sehr ähnlich sind. Die Unterscheidung, wer welchen Sub-Dialekt spricht, hängt dabei vorwiegend von der Zugehörigkeit zur jeweiligen sozialen Schicht ab.

Ein besonderer Wiener Dialekt wird im Wienerlied gepflegt, der seine geographischen Wurzeln in den Weinanbaugebieten im Nordwesten der Stadt hat (700 Hektar Weingärten liegen im Gebiet der Millionenstadt, die, nach Berlin, die zweitgrößte Stadt im deutschen Sprachraum ist). Sänger und Musikgruppen wie [Ostbahn Kurti](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Ostbahn), [Roland Neuwirth & Extremschrammeln](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremschrammeln), [Wanda](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wanda_(Band)), [5/8erl in Ehr’n](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/5/8erl_in_Ehr%E2%80%99n), [Seiler und Speer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiler_und_Speer) (letztere aus Bad Vöslau, ca. 10 km südlich von Wien) verwenden diesen Dialekt für ihre Texte.

Die Band Sumawind stammt zwar geographisch aus Wien, lässt sich musikalisch und thematisch aber eher den Schlagerbands im alpenländischen Raum zuordnen. Die Musik dieser Band ist nicht typisch für Wien.

---

### Originaltext im Wiener Dialekt

> **Sumawind - Wüde Weiber**
>
> Mai Heaz is wüd wia die Nocht.
> Kumm, schau ma in die Augn.
> I hob heit scho an di docht,
> du kaunst ma bild vatraun.
>
> ho
> I was genau wos i wü,
> kumm hea zu mia, mei Bua.
> I zag da wea i bin,
> i azöh da wos, hoach zua.
>
> Wüde Weiba hom a Heaz aus Goid
> Wüde Weiba
> A raue Schåle mit an wachn Kean.
> Wüst mi zähmen muast scho wissn wia.
>
> Wüde Weiba hom a Heaz aus Goid
> Wüde Weiba
> Los mi dei Liab gspian und a echtes Gfüh in dia,
> donn bleib i bei dia a Lebn long.
>
> Mei Bua
>
> I hob a Feia in mir,
> die Gluat in meine Augn.
> Du bist so stoak wia a Stia,
> i glaub des kunnt ma daugn
>
> hoa
> I bin a wüde Henn,
> kimm sei mei Gocklhahn.
> Mei Herzerl schenk i dia,
> mit mia kaunst Pferdln stöhn
>
> Wüde Weiba hom a Heaz aus Goid
> Wüde Weiba
> A raue Schåle mit an wachn Kean.
> Wüst mi zähmen muast scho wissn wia.
>
> Wüde Weiba hom a Heaz aus Goid
> Wüde Weiba
> Los mi dei Liab gspian und a echtes Gfüh in dia,
> donn bleib i bei dia a Lebn long.
>
> Madl, du host ma mein Kopf vadraht,
> mei Heaz, des gheat nua dia.
>
> Mit Haut und Hoa mecht i di gspian,
> duachs Leben gehn mit dia.
>
> Wüde Weiba hom a Heaz aus Goid
>
> a ho
> ooh
> Wüde Weiber
> Wüde Weiber
>
> juhuhu

---

### Standarddeutsche Übersetzung

> **Sommerwind - wilde Frauen (Weiber)<sup>1</sup>**
>
> Mein Herz ist wild wie die Nacht.
> Komm, schau mir in die Augen.
> Ich habe heute schon an dich gedacht,
> du kannst mir blind vertrauen.
>
> ho
> Ich weiß genau was ich will,
> komm her zu mir mein Junge (Bube)<sup>2</sup>.
> Ich zeige dir wer ich bin,
> ich erzähle dir etwas, höre zu. (horche zu)<sup>3</sup>
>
> Wilde Frauen haben ein Herz aus Gold
> Wilde Frauen
> Eine raue Schale<sup>4</sup> mit einem weichen Kern.
> Willst du mich zähmen, musst du schon wissen wie.
>
> Wilde Frauen haben ein Herz aus Gold
> Wilde Frauen
> Lass mich deine Liebe spüren und ein echtes Gefühl in dir,
> dann bleibe ich bei dir ein Leben lang.
>
> Mein Junge
>
> Ich habe ein Feuer in mir,
> die Glut in meinen Augen.
> Du bist so stark wie ein Stier,
> ich glaube, das könnte mir gefallen (taugen)<sup>5</sup>.
>
> hoa
> Ich bin eine wilde Henne,
> komm sei mein Hahn (Gockelhahn)<sup>6</sup>.
> Mein Herzchen<sup>7</sup> schenke ich dir,
> mit mir kannst du Pferde stehlen.
>
> Wilde Frauen haben ein Herz aus Gold
> Wilde Frauen
> Eine raue Schale mit einem weichen Kern.
> Willst du mich zähmen, musst du schon wissen wie.
>
> Wilde Frauen haben ein Herz aus Gold
> Wilde Frauen
> Lass mich deine Liebe spüren und ein echtes Gefühl in dir,
> dann bleibe ich bei dir ein Leben lang.
>
> Mädchen (Mädel)<sup>8</sup>, du hast mir meinen Kopf verdreht,
> mein Herz, das gehört nur dir.
>
> Mit Haut und Haaren möchte ich dich spüren,
> durch das Leben gehen mit dir.
>
> Wilde Frauen haben ein Herz aus Gold
>
> a ho
> ooh
> Wilde Frauen
> Wilde Frauen
>
> juhuhu

---

### Anmerkungen

1. Das Wort *»Weib«* hat im Dialekt eine weit weniger abwertende Bedeutung als in einem standardsprachlichen Text. Daher habe ich mich dafür entschieden, für die Übersetzung das Wort *»Frau«* zu wählen. Man könnte aber durchaus berechtigterweise argumentieren, dass dem Wort *»Frau«* der animalische Beigeschmack fehlt, der im Wort *»Weib«* mitschwingt, und in diesem Lied eine durchaus wichtige Rolle spielt (im Lied kommen Pferde, Stiere, Hühner und Hähne vor).
2. Das Dialektwort *»Bub«* bedeutet nicht nur *»männliches Kind«* sondern kann auch *»junger Mann«* oder auch *»Liebhaber«* bedeuten.
3. Standarddeutsch muss es entweder *»ich höre zu«* (mit *»zu«*) oder *»ich horche«* (ohne *»zu«*) heißen. Im Dialekt werden aber sowohl *»i hea zua«* also auch  *»i huach zua«* mit *»zua«* verwendet.
4. Die Sängerin singt *»Schåle«* (mit einem Vokal in der ersten Silbe, der zwischen A und O angesiedelt ist). Das ist aber eine Anpassung an das Standarddeutsche. Im Wiener Dialekt wird stattdessen in Wahrheit das Wort *»Schoin«* verwendet (nur eine Silbe, mit einem Diphthong, bei dem das i kaum hörbar ist).
5. Das Wort *»taugen«* wird Standarddeutsch meist nur in der Bedeutung *»ist geeignet«* verwendet. Im Dialekt ist es ein Synonym für *»gefallen«* (*»das gefällt mir« = »des taugt ma«*). Das Verb *»gfoin«* (*»des gfoit ma«*) existiert aber ebenfalls.
6. Gerade wenn es darum geht, die stolze Männlichkeit des Hahnes herauszustellen, wird im Dialekt bevorzugt der Hahn zum Gockelhahn.
   Die Erwähnung von bäuerlichen Nutztieren in Liedtexten ist ein sehr starker Hinweis auf eine Sozialisierung im ländlichen Raum, und völlig untypisch für eine Millionenstadt wie Wien. (In Wien gibt es zwar unerwartet große landwirtschaftliche Nutzflächen, diese Flächen werden aber vorwiegend zum Anbau von Wein und Gemüse verwendet. Viehzucht findet in Wien gar nicht statt, Geflügelzucht höchstens für den privaten Eigenbedarf in Vorgärten am Stadtrand.)
7. Standarddeutsch gibt es nur ein Diminuierungssuffix, nämlich *»-chen«.* In alemannischen und bairischen Dialekten gibt es stattdessen andere Suffixe (*»-el«, »-le«, »-erl«, »-erle«*), wobei in den donaubairischen Dialekten, und somit im Wiener Dialekt vor allem *»-erl«* dominiert. Das geht in Östereich sogar so weit, dass es auch in der Österreicheichen Standardvarietät des Deutschen eine Reihe von Wörtern gibt, die mit diesem Suffix gebildet werden, und in Zeitungen, Schulbüchern usw. verwendet werden: *Sackerl, Krügerl, Häferl.*
8. Das Wort *»Mädl«* bzw. *»Mädel«* ist ein weiteres Beispiel für einen alternativen Diminuierungssuffix. Für die Bedeutung des Wortes selbt gilt sinngemäß, was schon über den *Buben* gesagt wurde, diesmal auf weibliche Personen bezogen.

Comment: Ich glaubte mal gelesen zu haben, dass es *bairische* Dialekte sind, weil *bayrisch* eine geografische Bezeichnung ist, während das mit i für die Sprache steht. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekte_in_Bayern#/media/Datei:Oberdeutsche_Mundarten.png

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Danke, das verwechsle ich ständig. Hab's gerade korrigiert. Aber: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Deutsche_Dialekte.PNG dort steht in der zweiten Spalte zwar "52 = Mittelbairisch" (mit I), ganz rechts aber "C Ostoberdeutsch (Bayrisch-Österreichisch)" und (Donaubayrisch) (beide mit Y)

Comment: So umfassend wie diese Antwort ist beantwortet sie die Frage in dieser Form mE nur halb, da sie auf den Begriff "wüde" nicht eingeht. Man kann das zwar aus der Übersetzung her ableiten, aber, wenn man schon all das zusätzlich erläutert wonach gar nicht gefragt wurde, scheint das "wüde" vergessen worden zu sein.

Comment: @mtwde: In der Übersetzung ist aber ganz klar ersichtlich, dass *»wüde«* mit *»wilde«* übersetzt wurde. Was genau fehlt dir?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, es ist meckern auf hohem Niveau ^^. Aber du gehst in den Anmerkungen auf so viele Worte ein nach denen nicht gefragt wurde, aber die Bedeutung des Worts "wüde", nach dem eben explizit gefragt wurde, muss man aus dem Kontext der Übersetzung ableiten. Dadurch wirkt es ein wenig als hättest du es vergessen. Vor allem, da du ja "Weiber" gleich als erstes erläuterst.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, *wüde* is non-standard German for 'wild'. See for example [This entry](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCde_Jogd) in the Boarische Wikipedia. (The entry is "Wüde Jogd" in Bavarian and corresponds to "Wilde Jagd" in German, "Wild Hunt" in English.)

Comment: So they must be singing in the Bavarian dialect. That's why I can't understand much.

Comment: @JimS It's actually austruan dialect, which ist partially close to Bavarian.

Comment: Warum antwortest du auf English wenn die Frage doch auf Deutsch gestellt wurde?

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast  -- Sorry, I'm not fluent in German (yet). I could run the answer through Google translate if you want :)

Comment: @RDBury: Please quote the relevant part of the link you used. Your link might go offline in another timeframe than German.SE. Thanks.

Comment: @Shegit Brahm -- The relevant part of the is really just the title, but I added it to the answer just in case.